# Low-dimensional irreducible 2-modular representations of the symmetric group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, modular-representation-theory

I apologize if this question is a little too basic for MathOverflow, but it's somewhat outside of my background and I'm frustrated that the answer doesn't seem to be explicit in the literature even though I suspect it's easily known by the experts.

What are the lowest-dimensional irreducible representations over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of the full symmetric group $S_n$ and in particular whether there exist any of dimension $\leq n - 2$ (resp. $\leq n - 3$) if $n$ is odd (resp. even)?

I know that for each $n \geq 3$ we have the $(n - 1)$-dimensional standard representation over *any* field. Moreover, if $n$ is even, we get an $(n - 2$)-dimensional representation as a quotient of this over characteristic $2$ (because then the vector with all $1$'s lies in the standard representation but is fixed by all of $S_n$). It's easy to see that these representations are irreducible. What I would specifically like to know is whether or not they are the lowest-dimensional irreducible representations of $S_n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$.

(I'm curious about slightly more general questions as well, like whether or not the analogous representations to the ones I described above are the lowest-dimensional over any given positive characteristic.)

Comment: In characteristic 2, the sign representation and the trivial representation coincide, so your caveat "I mean modulo tensoring with the 1-dimensional sign representation" ought to be unnecessary.

Comment: The exceptions come from the isomorphism $GL_4(\mathbb{F}_2)=A_8$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the minimality of these degrees for representations over the field of order $2$ was proved originally in the paper

A. Wagner. [The faithful linear representations of least degree of $S_n$ and $A_n$ over a field of characteristic $2$](https://eudml.org/doc/172514). Math. Zeit, 151:127–137, 1976; [DOI: 10.1007/BF01241824](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01241824).

For $S_n$, the minimal nontrivial irreducible representation has dimension $n-1$ or $n-2$ for all $n$, as you conjectured. For $A_n$, there are a couple of exceptions: $A_7$ and $A_8$ have representations of degree $4$.

Comment: Ah, the title certainly looks promising!

Answer (score 10):

An earlier reference for the minimality of these degrees over any field is L.E.Dickson, [Representations of the general symmetric group as linear groups in finite and infinite fields](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1908-1500805-8), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 9 (1908), 121-148. This can be found in Dickson's Collected Works.

Comment: Link: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1908-009-02/S0002-9947-1908-1500805-8/S0002-9947-1908-1500805-8.pdf

Comment: Great, from this link I first understand why one says "modular": this is because the characteristic of the field was called "module".

Answer (score 7):

If you fix a prime $p$ then for $n$ sufficiently large these $n-1$ or $n-2$ dimensional representations are indeed of minimal dimension.  For this I believe the right reference is "[On the minimal dimensions of irreducible representations of symmetric groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100000803)" by Gordon James, although I don't have access to it at the moment.

I certainly would not be surprised if there are counterexamples for small $n$ and $p$ though.